# PHP update multiple rows with id and selects

Tags: php, mysql

This code picks up the ID of the check box checked correctly, however it chooses the select dropdown from my first select not the one I changed. Is there a way to fix this? Im using

```
<select name="status[]"><option value="1">active</option><option value="0">inactive</option></select>
```

here is my process code.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


// find out how many records there are to update

$size = count($_POST['id']);

// start a loop in order to update each record
$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
// define each variable
$id = $_POST['id'][$i];
$status= $_POST['status'][$i];

// do the update and print out some info just to provide some visual feedback
$query = "UPDATE users SET status = '$status' WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
print "$status | $id<br /><br /><em>Updated!</em><br /><br />";
++$i;
}
mysql_close();
}
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection...

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions. Please use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Despite @ChristopheD and webbiedave candid and not very helpful response...typical of a 20,000 rep user, they are right.  You should use PDO or a Framework that will handle SQL injection correctly. Where does the id come from?  Is it check boxes?

Comment: How do you know which status relates to which user ? And why do you have multiple statuses ?

Comment: I think we will need more of the HTML to see a larger picture to help you out.

Comment: @mediaslave: my comment most honestly was just a quick note for James, and I certainly did not want to sound arrogant or demeaning. The web is full of examples of sql injection and how to prevent it, it was meant as a reminder to the topic starter to google a bit about it...

Comment: @ChristopheD I just would hope for a more constructive question that would lead to an answer that would also "warn" against sql injection.  SOF is starting to get a rep of "only for the elite" and I would hate to see that happen.  Help a newb out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments, however, I'll just provide a quick answer to the question.

I'd do something like this for simplicity in the HTML.  The array indices can simply echo from a counter in PHP or entered statically if it won't change based on anything else.  Simply increase this index with each item.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id[0]" value="1"> Some Text
<select name="status[0]">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Now for the PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    foreach($_POST['id'] as $i=>$value) {
        if($value == 1) {
            // define each variable
            $id = $_POST['id'][$i];
            $status= $_POST['status'][$i];

            // do the update and print out some info just to provide some visual feedback
            $query = "UPDATE users SET status = '$status' WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
            mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
            print "$status | $id<br /><br /><em>Updated!</em><br /><br />";
        }

    }
    mysql_close();
}
```

EDIT:

I forgot to mention you can set the value of the checkbox to whatever you need it to be.  Just be sure the `if($value==1)` checks for a valid result (for example `>0` if all of your Id's are positive).

Comment: Thanks, I do know about the sql injection, but was posting my test code for quick help. I add the injection security after the fact. I also keep my DB strings in the registry keys so no one can ever get them.

Comment: One additional question, I have a selected value for the current value in the select option. What I have found is that PHP ignores the selected value and instead uses the selected version in display. Is there a way to overwrite that, or ensure it uses the actual value?

Comment: <option value="1" <?php if($defaultValue == 1) echo "selected"; ?>>option name</option>

Comment: Thats what I am doing now, what i am saying is that for some reason it sees that selected value as the value when the form submits, not the value the user changes it to.

Comment: Can you paste the actual html output for one if the selects?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks! it was grabbing the first select element, not the one I checked with the ID. All good.